# Solution in Visual Studio 2019 shows 0 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project, solution

I'm very new to programming and Visual Studio 2019 Community. I am trying to create a new project; a Console Application in C# for Windows. However, when I create it, the solution shows 0 projects. If i try to add to the solution and create a new Console Application it still shows as 0 projects. However, if I navigate the files on my computer it shows that the projects were created. How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: This is one of the few times it might be useful to put an image in your question of the  explorer.. Obviously this shouldn't be happening, and would represent a bug or glitch.. Though, lets cancel out that you might be looking at the wrong thing

Comment: Please provide the steps you have followed to create the new project/solution.

Comment: To create the project, I clicked on "create new project" --> C# language, Windows platform, Console --> Console Application --> Project name: Exercise 1 (for some reason this changes both the project and solution names, but I rename the solution right after) --> (rename) Solution name: Programming 1 - Week 1 --> Target framework: .NET Core 3.1. This opens the terminal, yet solution shows 0 projects. I have tried reisntalling the 3.1 .NET SDK in order to follow a previous comment in here, still no change

Comment: Navigate to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk and see if you can find folders associated with different sdk versions. If you can’t find any folder there that means the sdk is not installed.
Or try to run the dotnet --list-sdks command to see if it lists the sdk.
Then you can try to edit envrionment Variables.
Please refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209536/microsoft-visual-studio-2019-the-project-file-cannot-be-opened-unable-to-locat

Answer (score 0):

You can add them by:

Right-click the solution file => Add => Existing Project and choose the project you wish to add.

This will add some lines to the solution file which will connect the solution to the projects you will add.

Comment: I have just tried this, however I get an error message "Unable to locate the .NET SDK." I have just reisntalled the 3.1 .NET SDK and still the same error message appears. How can I install it properly/stop the error message from showing?

Answer (score -1):

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\` moving this path (env variable - system variable) upward worked for me.   In my case there are two paths: one is program files and another one is program files (x86) , so just moved `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` this path above.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving this path upward"? How does one "move a path
"? Please [edit] your answer to clarify. Welcome to Stack Overflow!