# Visual Studio 2019 "attach" instead of "start" issue

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, console-application

Basically, after installing visual studio on my second computer I went to make a simple console application. Instead of saying start or letting me run the program it would just say attach. It works perfectly fine on my other computer and I downloaded vs the exact same way on both.

I also tried doing "dotnet --version" in  the command prompt on both computers and the computer that works is able to find a .NET version on my computer but the one with the issue cant, it says I haven't downloaded it... when I go to download .NET separately it still doesn't work.

In my solution explorer it says "0 projects" even though I clearly have a project file in the folder along with the solution. When I try to add an existing project it simply doesn't let and says "The project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate the .NET SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version".

I also tried the solution from this thread: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2019: The project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate the .NET SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209536/microsoft-visual-studio-2019-the-project-file-cannot-be-opened-unable-to-locat)
and it didn't change anything.

I've tried reinstalling and repairing visual studio and even that didn't help at all.

If any of you have any idea what I could do to fix this that'd be great!

Comment: I'm afraid the reference link you provide may not work. Could you please have a try with Han's suggestion to create a new file manually? If it does not work you may reinstall VS 2019.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT I've tried both reinstalling and repairing visual studio and it didn't help at all. Hans suggestion didn't work either :/

Comment: @HansPassant I've tried that and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when you open the project from the project file, from the folder that contains it, instead of opening it from VS. Try open VS first, and then browse to open your project and should work. Another way to solve it is clicking on "reload" once the project is open.

Some other times it happens when you open the (.cs) file instead of the project file. [Attach - start issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/attach-instead-of-start-issue/308134)

Comment: I cant open projects. When I do I get an error and when I open the solution it says I have 0 projects in the solution. I don't understand how to reload...

Comment: Try this: right click on the solution name
select 'Add'
select 'Existing Project'
in browser window go to your project folder and select 'YourProjectName.csproj' file (.csproj file of project)
and the project will be added! so Done!

Comment: When I try to open an existing project it just gives me the following error: "The project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate the .NET SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version".