# Project file cannot be opened. Which component of Visual Studio to update?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

One of the project files in my C# solution cannot be loaded. When I try, I get the message,
`error  : The project file cannot be opened. C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk not found. Check that a recent enough .NET SDK is installed and/or increase the version specified in global.json.`

How can I find out which component of Visual Studio (or whatever) needs to be updated, installed, repaired or configured (or whatever)?

There is no `global.json` file in my project, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit envrionment Variables.

Right click on This PC -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables

Add [install path] to the variable path.C:\Program Files\dotnet\

Restart visual studio.

My answer is from this case, you can refer to it
[Microsoft Visual Studio 2019: The project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate the .NET SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209536/microsoft-visual-studio-2019-the-project-file-cannot-be-opened-unable-to-locat)

https://superuser.com/questions/1431833/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-locate-net-core-sdk