# Visual Studio 2022 installation issue

Tags: installation, project, visual-studio-2022, solution

After installing Visual Studio 2022 Community Version on Windows 10, it does not work. I cannot add a project to a solution. Please see the error information:

The project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate the .net disk. Check if it is installed, your path is configured for the correct architecture, and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.

I would appreciate it if any one can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual Studio 2019: The project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate the .NET SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209536/microsoft-visual-studio-2019-the-project-file-cannot-be-opened-unable-to-locat)

Comment: Yes. The issue got solved. Thanks.