# Azure Functions Project failed to load in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to open a solution in VS 2019 on a new computer.

I get the latest code from source control, opened the solution. All the other projects were loaded, except one Azure Functions Project: "The project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate the .NET SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version."

I verified that the 'Azure Development Pack' is checked in VS 2019 installer.

Then I tried to create a new Azure Functions project, I got the same error.

The project is using .Net Framework 4.6.2, it is working fine in my old computer.

Any help is much appreciated!

I verified that the 'Azure Development Pack' is checked in VS 2019 installer.

I tried to add the SDK folder to the Path enviroment variable - I don't really know what is the SDK in the error message, as all other projects are OK - console app, class library app

Restarted visual studio

Restarted the computer

Still the same error

Comment: Do you have .Net Framework [4.6.2 DEV Apps](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net462) installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed. Other projects in the same solution also use 4.6.2, and those work fine.

Comment: I gave up. Tried everything in VS2019, even uninstall and reinstall, not working.

Installed vs 2022, just worked.

Answer (score 0):

As your Function App is created in .Net Framework 4.6.2, You need to install that tool in the Visual Studio 2019 via Visual Studio Installer like below:-

[image]

Also, Refer the SO thread answer1 [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209536/microsoft-visual-studio-2019-the-project-file-cannot-be-opened-unable-to-locat) and Stack Exchange answer2 **[here](https://superuser.com/questions/1431833/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-locate-net-core-sdk)** to resolve the same error.

Check your Local system path and add the below variable in **`System variables > Path > C:\Program Files\dotnet`**

[image]

And remove the path with **`C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet`** **x86** as per the comment by Dadwals to resolve the error.

According to the Stack Exchange answer2 link above:-

Remove the **global.json** from your Directory and that will resolve your issue as the newest version of **`.net core sdk`** can build the apps by default and support earlier versions too.

As **`.Net 4.8`** is supported version for **Azure Functions Isolated Process** you can make create the Function with the same version like below:-

[image]

**Isolated Function csproj file:-**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***I agree with your comments, Using Visual Studio 2022 is preferable.***